# Matching (pairing) tokens (eg, brackets or quotes)

Tags: php, tokenize, code-completion, brackets

In short, I need a function which attempts a rudimentary code fix by adding brackets/quotes were necessary, **for parsing purposes.** That is, the **resulting code is not expected to be runnable.**

Let's see a few examples:

```
[1] class Aaa { $var a = "hi";       =>  class Aaa { $var a = "hi"; }
[2] $var a = "hi"; }                 =>  { $var a = "hi"; }
[3] class { a = "hi; function b( }   =>  class { a = "hi; function b( }"}
[4] class { a = "hi"; function b( }  =>  class { a = "hi"; function b() {}}
```

**PS:** The 4th example above looks quite complicated, but in fact, it's quite easy. If the engine finds an ending bracket token which doesn't match with the stack, it should the opposite token before that one. As you can see, this works pretty well.

---

As a function signature, it looks like: `balanceTokens($code, $bracket_tokens, $quote_tokens)`

The function I wrote works using a stack. Well, it doesn't exactly *work*, but it does use a stack.

```
function balanceTokens($code, $bracket_tokens, $quote_tokens){
    $stack = array(); $last = null; $result = '';
    foreach(str_split($code) as $c){
        if($last==$c && in_array($c, $quote_tokens)){
            // handle closing string
            array_pop($stack);
        }elseif(!in_array($last, $quote_tokens)){
            // handle other tokens
            if(isset($bracket_tokens[$c])){
                // handle begining bracket
                $stack[] = $c;
            }elseif(($p = array_search($c, $bracket_tokens)) != false){
                // handle ending bracket
                $l = array_pop($stack);   
                if($l != $p)$result .= $p;
            }elseif(isset($quote_tokens[$c])){
                // handle begining quote
                $stack[] = $c;
                $last = $c;
            }// else other token...
        }
        $result .= $c;
    }
    // perform fixes
    foreach($stack as $token){
        // fix ending brackets
        if(isset($bracket_tokens[$token]))
            $result .= $bracket_tokens[$token];
        // fix begining brackets
        if(in_array($token, $bracket_tokens))
            $result = $token . $result;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

The function is called like this:

```
$new_code = balanceTokens(
    $old_code,
    array(
        '<' => '>',
        '{' => '}',
        '(' => ')',
        '[' => ']',
    ),
    array(
        '"' => '"',
        "'" => "'",
    )
);
```

Yes, it's quite generic, there aren't any hard-coded tokens.

I haven't the slightest idea why it's not working...as a matter of fact, I don't even know if it should work. I admit I didn't put much thought into writing it. Maybe there are obvious issues which I'm not seeing.

Comment: I wonder how it will behave if I pass `$var a = "{";` as the input code

Comment: @Alexander There's a special case for (quoted) strings, it will ignore anything after a quote up till it finds the next matching quote.

Comment: There are much more cases. I suppose you don't expect to cover them all, right?

Comment: You are being too full of yourself.

Comment: By the way, you forgot to reset `$last` after handling the quote ending. So, It gets stuck in the first condition

Comment: Not to ruin anything, next to quotes there are these other doc-type strings with <<< and such.

Comment: I don't intend to cover those right now.

Comment: Chritsian did you ever consider to divide the problem? For example, one part is a tekenizer and the other your parser? This normally helps a lot to not do both things at once which is oftern harder.

Comment: Hmm, good idea. If the end (working) result is small enough, I could merge the two then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative implementation (which does more aggressive balancing):

```
function balanceTokens($code) {
    $tokens = [
        '{' => '}',
        '[' => ']',
        '(' => ')',
        '"' => '"',
        "'" => "'",
    ];
    $closeTokens = array_flip($tokens);
    $stringTokens = ['"' => true, '"' => true];

    $stack = [];
    for ($i = 0, $l = strlen($code); $i < $l; ++$i) {
        $c = $code[$i];

        // push opening tokens to the stack (for " and ' only if there is no " or ' opened yet)
        if (isset($tokens[$c]) && (!isset($stringTokens[$c]) || end($stack) != $c)) {
            $stack[] = $c;
        // closing tokens have to be matched up with the stack elements
        } elseif (isset($closeTokens[$c])) {
            $matched = false;

            while ($top = array_pop($stack)) {
                // stack has matching opening for current closing
                if ($top == $closeTokens[$c]) {
                    $matched = true;
                    break;
                }

                // stack has unmatched opening, insert closing at current pos
                $code = substr_replace($code, $tokens[$top], $i, 0);
                $i++;
                $l++;
            }

            // unmatched closing, insert opening at start
            if (!$matched) {
                $code = $closeTokens[$c] . $code;
                $i++;
                $l++;
            }
        }
    }

    // any elements still on the stack are unmatched opening, so insert closing
    while ($top = array_pop($stack)) {
        $code .= $tokens[$top];
    }

    return $code;
}
```

Some examples:

```
$tests = array(
    'class Aaa { public $a = "hi";',
    '$var = "hi"; }',
    'class { a = "hi; function b( }',
    'class { a = "hi"; function b( }',
    'foo { bar[foo="test',
    'bar { bar[foo="test] { bar: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1}',
);
```

Passing those to the function gives:

```
class Aaa { public $a = "hi";}
{$var = "hi"; }
class { a = "hi; function b( )"}
class { a = "hi"; function b( )}
foo { bar[foo="test"]}
bar { bar[foo="test"] { bar: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some coffee **:)**, I came up with a (somewhat) working prototype function.

You can see it [in action here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Ty8RW5). However, it is slightly modified to add some (shiny) debug output.

```
    /**
     * Fix some possible issues with the code (eg, incompleteness).
     * @param string $code The code to sanitize.
     * @param array $bracket_tokens List of bracket tokens where the index is the begin bracket and the value is the end bracket.
     * @param array $quote_tokens List of quote tokens where the index is the begin quote and the value is the end quote.
     * @return string The sanitized code.
     */
    function css_sanitize($code, $bracket_tokens, $quote_tokens){
        $result = '';
        $stack = array();
        $last = '';
        foreach(str_split($code) as $c){
            if(in_array($c, $quote_tokens) && $last==$c){
                array_pop($stack);
                $last = '';
            }elseif(!in_array($last, $quote_tokens)){
                if(isset($bracket_tokens[$c])){
                    $stack[] = $c;
                }elseif(($p = array_search($c, $bracket_tokens)) != false){
                    if($last != $c){
                        $result .= $p;
                    }else{
                        array_pop($stack);
                        $last = (($p = count($stack)) > 1) ? $stack[$p] : '';
                    }
                }elseif(isset($quote_tokens[$c])){
                    $stack[] = $c;
                    $last = $c;
                }
            }
            $result .= $c;
        }
        foreach(array_reverse($stack) as $token){
            if(isset($bracket_tokens[$token])){
                $result .= $bracket_tokens[$token];
            }
            if(in_array($token, $bracket_tokens)){
                $result = $token . $result;
            }
            if(isset($quote_tokens[$token])){
                $result .= $quote_tokens[$token];
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
```